# How to list citing papers under each of my paper?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I have papers p1, p2, p3, .... Under each of them, i'd like to list papers that cite them:

```
p1
[1] c11
[2] c12
...

p2
[1] c21
[2] c22
...

...
```

I can build `*.bib` files for each of my papers, but I don't know how to use them to form the above formatting.

p1, p2, ... are in `mine.bib`.
c11, c12, ... are in `citee1.bib`.
c21, c22, ... are in `citee2.bib`.
...

Comment: What I'd try to do is to add the papers to be cited in a field of the entry, and massage that into something that tricks BibTeX into spitting out what you want. Probably using Perl, as that is what I'm most familiar with.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal working example. How do you create your bibliography? Do you use `biblatex`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `biblatex` (and `biber` as backend). The key point is to use the `related` field provided by `biblatex`. This field stores a list of citation keys (and the solution uses the value `citing` for the field `relatedtype`). After that we have to define how to render the list of `related`. A simple way is to use an enumerated list, and for each item is rendered by using the appropriate driver.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
author = "Last, First",
title = "title",
journal = "journal",
year = "2011",
related = {second,third},
relatedtype = {citing}
}
@article{second,
author = "Last, First",
title = "title",
journal = "journal",
year = "2012",
related = {one,third},
relatedtype = {citing}
}
@article{third,
author = "Last, First",
title = "title",
journal = "journal",
year = "2013",
related = {second,one},
relatedtype = {citing}
}
@article{fourth,
author = "Last, First",
title = "title",
journal = "journal",
year = "2014",
}

\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\iffieldundef{related}{\finentry}{}}
\newcommand{\tempa}[1]{
    \item \entrydata{#1}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}\adddot 
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:citing}{\par Cited by:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \forcsvfield{\tempa}{related}
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{one}, \cite{second}, \cite{fourth}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

PS The various  references can be in multiple `.bib` files. Just load them with multiple `\addbibresources`.

EDIT: It is possible to change the title of the bibliography by using the `title` option of `\printbibliography`. Namely

```
\printbibliography[title={List of publications citing my publications}]
```

There are several ways to avoid printing the references. The simple one is to use `\nocite{key}` for each of the references to be inserted (and for which one wants to show the publication citing it).

Comment: How to change "References" to "List of papers citing my papers"?  Also, how to omit the main part of the article "Last 2011, Last 2012, Last 2014"?