# Biblatex: Custom date fields

Tags: biblatex

I've written my own entry types & bibliography driver as per [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287044/biblatex-citing-complex-nested-unpublished-sources/287268). I'd like entries to have two sets of dates (a seriesdate and a "normal" date), and have them both formatted exactly as `\printdate` does.

The seriesdate field is declared like so:

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date]{
    seriesdate}
```

However, using `\printfield{seriesdate}` outputs an empty string. Presumably, I'll have to tell biblatex how to output the field, possibly using `\DeclareFieldFormat` but I'm unsure how...

Comment: `date` fields need a bit more infrastructure if you want to have all the comfort that `biblatex` offers, have a look at my answer to [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) where we also deal with date fields.

Comment: Thanks @moewe that works, except I'd like to support date ranges, ie `seriesdate = {1854/1899}` should render as 1854–1899 like `\printdate` does. It currently renders as just the first year. Tried editing your minimal example with some ranges for testing to no avail.

Comment: I will have a look then, hang on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have a new `date`-type field you do not only need to ask for the date field, but also for the corresponding `datepart` fields.
You also need to define the new entry types and specify which fields are allowed for these types.

The command `\printseriesdate` can be used for pretty printing our new `seriesdate`.

Full MWE (adapted from your answer to [Biblatex: Citing complex nested unpublished sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287044/35864))

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@archivalsource{Test,
    title = {Test Source},
    contains = {ITEM1 and ITEM2}}

@archivalitem{ITEM1,
    title = {Transcript},
    author = {J. Doe},
    date = {1920-04-03},}

@archivalitem{ITEM2,
    title = {Report},
    author = {J. Moe},
    seriesdate = {1900-01-01/1900-06-06},}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{archival.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{
  archivalsource,
  archivalitem}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=literal]{
  contains}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  seriesdate}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archivalsource]{
  title,
  contains,
  seriesdate,
  seriesday,
  seriesendday,
  seriesendhour,
  seriesendminute,
  seriesendmonth,
  seriesendseason,
  seriesendsecond,
  seriesendtimezone,
  seriesendyear,
  serieshour,
  seriesminute,
  seriesmonth,
  seriesseason,
  seriessecond,
  seriestimezone,
  seriesyear}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archivalitem]{
  author,
  title,
  seriesdate,
  seriesday,
  seriesendday,
  seriesendhour,
  seriesendminute,
  seriesendmonth,
  seriesendseason,
  seriesendsecond,
  seriesendtimezone,
  seriesendyear,
  serieshour,
  seriesminute,
  seriesmonth,
  seriesseason,
  seriessecond,
  seriestimezone,
  seriesyear}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=archival, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{archivalitem}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace\textendash\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printseriesdate
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareListFormat{contains}{
  \item \entrydata{#1}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{archivalsource}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext{Contains:}%
  \begin{enumerate}%
  \printlist{contains}%
  \end{enumerate}%
  \iflistundef{contains}{\finentry}{}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]