# biblatex/biber patent citation support (based on zotero+bbl output)

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

I have a few questions on biblatex regarding patent citations which I think has very poor support only; my workflow is as follows:

- search Google patents
- use zotero connector and import patent to zotero
- zotero+betterbiblatex does all the magic
- then I export as .bib to use it in my document

This creates a patent like this:

```
@patent{abc123,
  title = {This is just an example},
  number = {US1234567A},
  date = {1990-01-01},
  keywords = {biblatex, example},
  holder = {Doe, John and Doe, Jessica}
}
```

In my document I use the following settings:

```
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99, sorting=none, backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

Okay, now my questions:

- there are only patent holders, no authors; in zotero there is no 'authors field' I could use once the type is set to 'patent'. The result is: \citeauthor does not work. I would prefer keeping the type 'patent' in zotero and not switch to misc.
- related issue: when typesetting the bibliography, the patent holders
  are listed after the title of the patent, not before it as it would
  be the case for authors, how to fix that?
- generally, I do not like that zotero exports the patents with just one date which happens to be the date the patent was granted; I would be much more interested in the filing/priority date (since it is often important when someone first had the idea, I'm not interested in seeing how long it took for the patent office to grant the patent ...). Is it possible to export the filing/priority date instead of the date the patent was granted? Alternatively, have both dates in the output?

Comment: If you add tags, please add tag wikis explaining their use. I doubt we really need `patent`. Not sure about `betterbiblatex` but, without some explanation, it will just be used vacuously. (Originally, I thought you were just using it to rant, but I gather from moewe's answer that may not be so.) If it is a Zotero thing, I should thing `zotero` sufficient. Otherwise, maybe `zotero-betterbiblatex` if it is really needed. But it will certainly be used by everyone with a biblatex question if no direction or explanation is given.

Comment: You may want to let me know where exactly you find my answer lacking, I'd be happy to update it (where I can) provided I get some feedback. I believe that the main part of your question here should be directed as a feature request to the Zotero developers (or failing that to the Zotero Better Bib(La)TeX developer, who is usually very happy to help quickly). There is little point in setting up a full-fledged `@patent` export in BBT's `postscript` einvironment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your already useful answer. I was hoping you could extend the part of "This are all things that should be fixed on the Zotero side". Having this working is quite important to me and I would be willing to even increase the bounty to have it fully working ;-)

Comment: I think/hope that the result will be useful to many other users of tex.stackexchange

Comment: My point is that really the Zotero people should fix this. Sure, one could *probably* cook something up with Better BibLaTeX's export options and a bit (a lot? of manual work), but why don't you ask Zotero to do the right thing? After all, if it is fixed on the Zotero side all Zotero users will benefit, not just the users that read this answer here.

Comment: BTW: For me this is not a matter of a bounty or internet points in general. I would have said the same had you just commented and not started a bounty or had you put up 1000 points. I just believe that there is not a lot won by fixing up deficiencies in Zotero's export mechanism when one could at least try and ask Zotero to do the right thing in the first place.

Comment: @cfr I'm fixing this in BBT, would you be willing to help out at https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/1060 ? I worl much better if there's a problem owner who can help test.

Comment: @retorquere Sorry, but I don't use Zotero. I did at one time, but it kept crashing my browser and I haven't used it for years.

Comment: Oh wait, you aren't the asker. @user26372? Care to join?

Answer (score 14):

Useful patent entries look like this (abridged from [biblatex-examples.bib](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/9a7c93ebb2d09f577d826bec01e761f422f088d5/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib))

```
@patent{laufenberg,
  author       = {Laufenberg, Xaver and Eynius, Dominique and Suelzle, Helmut
                  and Usbeck, Stephan and Spaeth, Matthias and Neuser-Hoffmann,
                  Miriam and Myrzik, Christian and Schmid, Manfred and Nietfeld,
                  Franz and Thiel, Alexander and Braun, Harald and Ebner,
                  Norbert},
  title        = {Elektrische Einrichtung und Betriebsverfahren},
  number       = 1700367,
  date         = {2006-09-13},
  holder       = {{Robert Bosch GmbH} and {Daimler Chrysler AG} and {Bayerische
                  Motoren Werke AG}},
  type         = {patenteu},
  url          = {http://v3.espacenet.com/textdoc?IDX=EP1700367},
}

@patent{sorace,
  author       = {Sorace, Ronald E. and Reinhardt, Victor S. and Vaughn, Steven
                  A.},
  title        = {High-Speed Digital-to-{RF} Converter},
  number       = 5668842,
  date         = {1997-09-16},
  holder       = {{Hughes Aircraft Company}},
  type         = {patentus},
}
```

In particular the Inventor (in Zotero's notation) should be exported to `author` and the Assignee/Holder should be exported to `holder` only if it does not coincide with the `author` list.

Furthermore a `@patent` entry should have a `type`, either the generic `type = {patent},` or preferable one of the available types `patenteu`, `patentus`, ... In case a non-generic type is used, the `number` field may contain the patent number without the country prefix.

The `location` field can and should be used if the (geographic) scope of the patent is different from the scope implied by the `type`. This is probably rarely the case, certainly for US patents with `type = {patentus},` that apply only to the US the `location` field is omissible.

**This are all things that should be fixed on the Zotero side or failing that could be requested as features at least for Better Bib(La)TeX**: https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues

> *edit:* Better Bib(La)TeX has implemented the required changes to make `@patent` more usable (given the limits of Zotero's input format) https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/1060 in version 5.0.199.
>
> The normal Zotero exporter is also going to be updated in due time (https://github.com/zotero/translators/pull/1742). With a bit of luck future versions will also support inputting `holder`/Assignee as a name list.

---

The date issue is a bit trickier. `biblatex` only allows one generic `date` for `@patent`s and does not specify whether that should be the filing date, priority date or issue date (date granted). Zotero is free to choose which date to export and I certainly won't argue against choosing the issue date.

On the `biblatex` side it would be possible to declare a new date (`prioritydate`, `filingdate`, `issuedate`, ...) and use that. See [Biblatex: Custom date fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288033/35864) and [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) for guidance.

On the Zotero side you will have to convince Zotero to export to the new date or to export an existing date to `date`.

Below you can see how to convince Zotero (with Better Bib(La)TeX) to export the filing date (`filingDate`) to `date`. But of course that strategy can be applied ion other cases as well.

For reference you may want to have a look at http://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/scripting/

Go to "Edit > Preferences > Better BibTeX > Advanced" and add the following to the postscript field (simplified thanks to [retorquere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27603/retorquere))

```
if (Translator.BetterBibLaTeX && item.itemType === 'patent') {
  this.add({ name: 'date', value: item.filingDate, enc: 'date' })
}
```

Zotero's Better BibLaTeX export should then export the filing date to the `date` field instead of the issue date.

Comment: Yeah, the holder/author thing we can certainly fix in Zotero (and Emiliano will want to fix in BBT). The type requires some judgment calls because Zotero doesn't have a controlled vocabulary for the respective fields, so we'd have to see how to do that. Emiliano (who wrote&maintains BBT) is typically more willing to just decree & document how this works in BBT than we'd be with Zotero where the same field has to work for other export formats and citations generated from Zotero. But generally I'd imagine we try to guess type & if we don't have a good guess use the generic type.

Comment: @adam.smith Well, the `@patent` support on the `biblatex` side does not go much further than `holder`, `author`, `type` and `location`, so with the `holder`/`author` and `type` thing you should be good. As for the `type` field only a limited number of identifiers is known by default: `patent`, `patent<country>`, `patreq` and `patreq<country>` where country is one of `de`, `eu`, `fr`, `uk` and `us`. I guess one could build a useful heuristics taking into account a possible alphabetic prefix of the number, the *Issuing Authority* and *Legal Status*.

Comment: @adam.smith Does your comment mean that this is 'officially' logged as a feature request for Zotero or should the OP open a proper one somewhere? From your comment I gather that even if something is changed on the Zotero side one would still have to file a similar request for Better BibTeX, is that correct?

Comment: yes, this is logged as a Zotero feature request. I'll open a ticket on BBT as well, but they're indeed separate.

Comment: @adam.smith Brilliant. Thank you. If the reports are open for the public would you mind posting them in the comments? I will then add them to the answer, so people can track the progress more easily.

Comment: BBT ticket here: https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/1060 . I'll post with Zotero PR later.

Comment: @moewe can you join on https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/1060 ? I'll need feedback to get this right.

Comment: The postscript can be slightly shorter because BBT will not output empty fields: if (Translator.BetterBibLaTeX && item.itemType === 'patent') this.add({ name: 'date', replace: true, value: item.filingDate, enc: 'date' })

Comment: The latest BBT has the changes outlined in this post BTW.

Comment: @retorquere Thanks for the improved postscript. I edited the question to update on BBT progress.

Comment: Thanks. I spotted one more (this one is on me): it can be further shortened to "this.add({ name: 'date', value: item.filingDate, enc: 'date' })"; "replace" is the default inside postscripts. also, "enc: 'date'" is not strictly required, but usually wanted here; with "enc: 'date'", BBT parses and normalizes the date, without it, whatever is in the filingDate will be output as-is.

Comment: @moewe stock Zotero PR is here: https://github.com/zotero/translators/pull/1742

Comment: Now are 400 :-) very good answer.